# How to Make the particular text field BOLD based on the Value from query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Good day. I am using MS Access 2007 and have a report which display the list of values (say 10 fields) from the basic SELECT * FROM table query.

I need to dynamically set the BOLD based on the particular value for the fifth field which was assigned from Query. if it doesn't match it should display normal.

```
E.g 
If Field_5 = "Agent" then
Field_5.FontBold = True
Else
Field_5.FontBold = False
End if
```

I tried the aforementioned code and it dont work. ALso i tried achieve it using below listed options.

```
Me.Field_5.FontBold = True
Field_5.Properties("fontweight") = 700
```

But nothing worked. Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the field property to rich text instead of plain text?